# Show dropdownlist in the View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a project in which, i am getting the client names from database table using the HomeController>Index Action method.

I want to send this list to Index view and display this list in the dropdownlist.

Request you to please help me with the View accordingly as i am new to MVC.

Home Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

var model = from c in 
_mdlCntxtcls.clients
where (DateTime.Now<=c.End_Date)
select c;

return View(model);
}
```

Model

```
public class Client
{
public int ClientID { get; set; }
public string Client_Names { get; set; }
public DateTime Start_Date { get; set; }
public DateTime End_Date { get; set; }
}
```

Please help as early as possible
Thank you

Comment: welcome to SO. Please review how to ask a good question on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Please state clearly what your problem is, what you have tried and what your expected result is.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a collection of `Client` objects to the view. So your view should be strongly typed to a collection of `Client` object to accept that as the (view) model data.

You can use the `DropDownList` html helper method to render a SELECT element from this view model data. You can create a `SelectList` object from this collection (your page model)

```
@model IEnumerable<YourNamespaceHere.Client>
@Html.DropDownList("StudentSelect",new SelectList(Model,"ClientID","Client_Names"))
```

This will render a SELECT element with name attribute value set to `StudentSelect`. Each options in the SELECT elemtn will have the `ClientID` as the value attribute value and `Client_Names` property value as the option text.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use viewbag or viewdata for send list of Client from controller to view and then you can put it in dropdown list.
In Controller you can use like :

```
List<SelectListItem> ClientList = new List<SelectListItem>();
using (dbContext db = new dbContext())
{
var Clients = db.Client.ToList();
foreach (var i in Clients)
{
ClientList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = i.Client_Name, Value = i.ClientID.ToString() });
}
}
ViewBag.ClientList = ClientList;
```

and in view side you can use that viewbag like :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Client, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ClistList)
```